# When assigning my objects to a grid, the attributes aren't there

Tags: python, class, object, nested-lists

The code I currently have which does not work

```
import pprint

class Kile(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

        kilevalue = 1

        def checkkilevalue(self):
            print (self.kilevalue)


kilecounter = 0
krid = []
for row in range(4):
    krid.append([])
    for colomn in range(4):
        krid[row].append([])
        for level in range(3):
            krid[row][colomn].append([])
            for tile in range(1):
                krid[row][colomn][0].append(Kile(kilecounter))
                kilecounter += 1            

print(kilecounter)
print(krid[0][0][0])
pprint.pprint(krid)
print(krid[0][0][0].kilevalue)
```

It shows the grid, it shows objects on the `[row][colomn][0]` places but it does not have the `.kilevalue` attribute

And now the other way it does work, but the way I don't need it.

```
class Tile(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

        tilevalue = 0

        def checktilevalue(self):
            print (self.tilevalue) 

trid = []
ttilecounter = 0
for row in range(3):
    trid.append([])
    for colomn in range(3):
        trid[row].append(Tile(ttilecounter))
        ttilecounter += 1


print(ttilecounter)
pprint.pprint(trid)
print(dir(trid[0][0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is that you assign `kilevalue` only in the function itself. I think you want that the `kilevalue` is assigned to the class.

To do so, Change `kilevalue = 1` to `self.kilevalue = 1`

EDIT: I think krid[row][colomn][0] is always None, because you're not Setting something to it.
Try adding `krid[row][colomn][0] = []` before `krid[row][colomn][0].append(Kile(kilecounter))`

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply!  I have changed it and it is the same result. its shows as an object yet not with the kilevalue  attribute

Comment: Hi and thanks again! I did that and it doest work. It actually has an object at all the krid[row][colomn][0] places but not with the attributes... if i print dir(krid[0][0][0]) it shows something : ['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__' etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your `kile` object does not have a `kilevalue` instance variable. In your `__init__()` method, you are just creating a local variable with name `kilevalue` not an instance variable.

You need to assign `1` to `self.kilevalue` in the `__init__()` method for `kilevalue` to be an instance variable -

```
def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.kilevalue = 1
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the replay. You method makes no difference in the outcome. It does work for the Tile object but not for the Kile object, although the are exact copy's of eachother on my pc. the only difference is 1 time nested list over the 2 times nested list.

Comment: it doesn't solve the issue with the `kilevalue` attribute not found error?

Comment: HI and no. The only difference i can see is the nested list part. What i see when i check dir(krid[0][0][0]) is a list not an object. so its something about 3 nested list and appending. i will report if i find a solution

Comment: your kilevalue object is at `krid[0][0][0][0]` , not `krid[0][0][0]` . Try with that.

Answer (score 0):

In the `__init__` method of `Kile`, you are assigning `kilevalue = 1` but you are using it as a property.

I think you need to change this to `self.kilevalue = 1` to be able to use it the way you want to.

A note: you are also defining the `checkkilevalue` inside `__init__` method. It will not be accessible from anywhere else (assuming that the indentation is correct in your example)

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply! I have changed the first part and it doenst matter. The indentation in the example was indeed not correct (sharp eyes you got). The indentation on my pc is an exact copy of the Tile object that is working. but it doenst matter the results are the same..

Answer (score 0):

so after a bit of tinkering and trying the answers and some more tinkering i found the solution. Although i dont truly understand it.

```
class Kile(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    kilevalue = 2

    def checkkilevalue(self):
        print (self.kilevalue)

krid = []
kilecounter = 0
for row in range(4):
    krid.append([])
    for colomn in range(4):
        krid[row].append([])
        for level in range(1):
            krid[row][colomn].append(Kile(kilecounter))
            kilecounter += 1
        for level in range(2):
            krid[row][colomn].append([])
```

so first i append the object to a 3rd list and then afterwards append two other empty list items to that list. and that works. Anyway thanks for the support :)